# Xcode Instrument screen goes black when recording

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

When I do time profile, after pressing record, the screen goes black (should be dynamic changed when I play with the app). Have anyone encountered the same problem?

[image]

Comment: Try by restarting the device.

Comment: restarting doesn't solve it. both simulator and real device shows the same black screen.

Comment: Did you solve this? I encountered this too

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem with Xcode 7.3. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Open Preferences in Instruments and **uncheck** the Always Use Deferred Mode check box,then restart Instruments.